# Unable to get output for test data, on cu.summary dataset in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have created decision tree from cu.summary dataset in R for which i got correct output.

But when i try to predict mileage(dependent variable in training data) by providing values for other four variable then i'm getting Error: "variable 'Reliability' was fitted with type "ordered" but type "factor" was supplied"

Dataset: **cu.summary**

**Variables in dataset: Mileage,
Price,
Country,
Reliability,
Type**

```
    libray(rpart)
    fit <- rpart(Mileage~Price + Country + Reliability + Type,method="anova",data=cu.summary)
    printcp(fit)
    plotcp(fit)
    summary(fit)
    par(mfrow=c(1,2))
    rsq.rpart(fit)
    plot(fit, uniform=TRUE)
    text(fit, use.n=TRUE , all=TRUE, cex=.8)
    post(fit,file = "Desktop/tree_reg.ps")
    plot(pfit, uniform=TRUE,main= "Regression tree")
    pfit<- prune(fit, cp=0.01160389)
    plot(pfit, uniform=TRUE,main= "Pruned regression Tree for mileage")
    text(pfit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
    post(fit,file = "Desktop/tree_pruned.ps")
    predict(fit,data.frame(Price=7000,Country="Japan",Reliability="worse",Type="Small"))
```

Output Window

[image: Output Window]

please help me to debug this code

Comment: Make sure the data type of `Reliability` in `cu.summary` matches the data type of `Reliability` in your `predict` data frame. As your error message tells you, there is a mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `Reliability` column into ordered factors (as in `cu.summary`) before running `predict`.

```
tmp <- data.frame(Price=7000,Country="Japan",Reliability="worse",Type="Small")
tmp$Reliability <- as.ordered(tmp$Reliability)
predict(fit, tmp)
```

Comment: Look at the structure of `cu.summary` (`str(cu.summary`). The columns `Country` and `Type` are factors while `Reliability` is an `Ord.factor`.

Comment: thank you it worked for me, can you tell me why we are converting only Reliability column to ordered factor, not the other ones.